# Sum specific cells from a column based on criteria from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three sheets. `ScoreInputs`, `RawScores` and `ScoreMatrix`.

`ScoreInputs` is basically a single column of raw input scores. [Score Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PythP.png)

In `ScoreMatrix`, the first row is a list of score categories, then going down, a non-empty value if that question applies to that category. [ScoreMatrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbwPw.png).

In `RawScoreCalc` I'm trying to do the proper summation of the values from `ScoreInputs` based on `ScoreMatrix`.

I've started with `=MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW() - 1, COLUMN() ) ), ScoreMatrix!$B1:$Z1)` which will tell me which is the proper column to query from `ScoreMatrix`, and then `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW() - 1, COLUMN() ) ), ScoreMatrix!$B1:$Z1))&":"&ADDRESS(200,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW() - 1, COLUMN() ) ), ScoreMatrix!$B1:$Z1))),"<>")` will tell me the number of non-zero rows, but I'm unsure how to parlay that into summing the matching rows from `ScoreInputs`.

So for example, [RawScoreCalc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeTWP.png), based on the `ScoreMatrix`, `LP1` should have the sum of cells `ScoreInput!B6`, `ScoreInput!B8`, `ScoreInput!B10`, etc. Which right now, I just did a static selection of the proper rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this:

```
=SUM((INDEX(ScoreMatrix!$B$2:$N$19,,MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())),ScoreMatrix!$B$1:$Z$1,0))="X")*ScoreInputs!$B$2:$B$19)
```

Remember that numbers of rows in `ScoreMatrix` and `ScoreInputs` must be equal.